# Is there a python api for texture painting?

Tags: python, texture-painting

Is there a means to script texture painting (cloning) in blender. I will have three uv maps, one for front , one for side and one the unwrapped mesh. I want to clone texture from the front and the side into the unwrapped texture. Does the blender python api allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.ops.paint.html

This official documentation has details on python api for all kinds of painting including texture painting.